# ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpUser' from 'locust'

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, locust

I am trying the locust quick start in my mac and I am getting this error for any import I try.
I have python 2.7 and python 3.7 installed in my machine but i use only python 3.7

```
➜  ~ python -V
Python 2.7.16
➜  ~ python3 -V
Python 3.7.5
```

my locust version is: 1.4.3

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/locust.py", line 3, in <module>
    from locust import HttpUser, task, between
ImportError: cannot import name 'HttpUser' from 'locust' (/Users/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/locust.py)```
````

Comment: If you type into the terminal `python3 -m pip list` does the module show up there? Are you using `python3 -m pip install` to install modules?

Comment: yes, the module shows up in the list
yes, I used pip3 install locust, not python3 -m pip install as i always do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you have named the locust file `locust.py` instead of `locustfile.py` as quick-start suggest. I think that perhaps that will be causing you to fail the imports from the same file.

Can't tell properly without a way to test it or more details related to how you are running locust.

Try changing the filename of the locust test scenarios

Comment: If this fixed your issue could you accept it as the answer?